# how to get value input file with jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

i want to get value input type with jquery, if im add a file on input file, i want to add more input type with value that file, and im use my code like this

```js
$('#show_input').append("<input type='file' value='" + URL.createObjectURL(event.target.files[i]) + "'>");
```

```html
<form action="myform.php" method="post" class="form-horizontal" enctype="multipart/form-data">
  <div id="show_input"></div>
  <input type="file" id="upload_file" name="upload_file[]" onchange="preview_image();" multiple/>
</form>
```

with my code value input type like this value="bloob:localhost..bla bla bla" how to fix this?

Comment: And what do you suppose `event.target` is in that context ?

Answer (score 0):

You are not closing the opening input tag and the closing tag is `</span>` instead of `</input>`

```
$('#show_input').append("<input type='file' value='"+URL.createObjectURL(event.target.files[i])+"'>  </input> ");
```

Comment: im sory that typo. yeah its true closing tag </input>